# What is the correct subnet Delegate Azure Storage account?

Tags: azure, subnet, vnet

I am creating subnets for a Vnet. I have 3 seperated Subnets. One for App services, another for Sql Database and third one for Storage accounts [blob and file]. Subnet with app services is delegated to Web and SQL database to SqlmanagedInstance. But I couldnt't find anything for storage account .
What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Storage Accounts are not "placed" inside a VNet/subnet since they are not compute resource like App Services which can get "VNet injected". If you want to connect to a Storage account via private addresses, [use Private Endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-private-endpoints)